# COPY into command allow to zip multiple files into single zip file while in Snowflake

Tags: copy, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Will the below "COPY into" command allow to zip multiple files into single zip file while in Snowflake while copying large volume of data.

copy into @my_stage/test.csv from TEST FILE_FORMAT = (TYPE = CSV compression=GZIP FIELD_OPTIONALLY_ENCLOSED_BY = '"' ESCAPE_UNENCLOSED_FIELD = NONE );

Thanks, Sudarshan

Answer (score 0):

If you want to unload all your data into one single file, you have to use the parameter `SINGLE=TRUE`.

Example from docs:

```
copy into @~ from home_sales
single = true;
```

More infos: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/copy-into-location.html#unloading-data-to-a-single-file